# Ubuntu 22.04 freeze on boot after successful install

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 22.04

I've installed the new Ubuntu 22.04 on my Samsung 550P (NP550P5C), but it freezes when it reboots after the installation!

After a lot of time spent, I suspect that the nvidia driver is the "villain".

I've made a minimal install and it boots, but when I install the `nvidia-driver-390` package it freezes on boot again.

To make it boot again, I've put `module_blacklist=nvidia` on the kernel line in the grub boot menu.

What is going on? How can I make it work?

```
System:
  Host: 550p Kernel: 5.15.0-27-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.2.0 Console: pty pts/1
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: SAMSUNG product: 550P5C/550P7C v: P09ABI serial: HX1K9QBD203259
  Mobo: SAMSUNG model: SAMSUNG_NP1234567890 v: SEC_SW_REVISION_1234567890ABCD
    serial: 123490EN400015 UEFI: American Megatrends v: P09ABI.026.141024.dg date: 10/24/2014
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i7-3630QM bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Ivy Bridge rev: 9
    cache: L1: 256 KiB L2: 1024 KiB L3: 6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1902 high: 2395 min/max: 1200/3400 cores: 1: 1259 2: 2395 3: 1248 4: 2395
    5: 2395 6: 1396 7: 1737 8: 2395 bogomips: 38312
  Flags: avx ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics vendor: Samsung Co driver: N/A bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GF108M [GeForce GT 620M/630M/635M/640M LE] vendor: Samsung Co driver: N/A
    bus-ID: 01:00.0
  Device-3: Silicon Motion WebCam SC-13HDL11939N type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 1-1.4:4
  Display: server: X.org v: 1.21.1.3 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.1 driver: X: loaded: vesa
    unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: N/A tty: 183x42
  Message: GL data unavailable in console for root.
```

Comment: Maybe try the 340 for your older hardware.  The "recovery" grub option add the "nomodeset" option to the kernel boot line, to allow running until the proprietary Nvidia drivers are installed.

Comment: I've done what you told, but it does not load nvidia module.

Comment: From https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/legacy-gpu/  the 390 driver should have worked, and did in the past on my 1000m.  After several attempts, maybe there are leftover "blacklists", check the /etc/modprobe.d files .  the only blacklist should be for nvidiafb

Comment: @ubfan1 I tried again today, clean install, blacklisted `nouveau`, `nvidiafb` and running `sudo update-initramfs -u`. I've made the install with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`, the system freezes again after reboot, it dows not boot even with recovery option as you said.
I don't what to do.

Comment: Try searching this site for 620m  (and 640m too) and see what others have done to fix this issue.  We know the card did work at one time with the 340-390 drivers, but with an old kernel.  There are maintained older kernels, if that turned out to be the only solution.

Comment: @ubfan1, nothing yet. Do you known how can I debug the boot? There is no log, it freezes before any log been writen. I installed the latest Manjaro to test and it didn't crash at all, it loads the nvidia module, so it's not my hardware. I want to use Ubuntu.

Comment: I would suggest trying the available release install media to find one which works. 21.10 is near the end of support, so try 20.04, a long term support rerlease.  I suppose even try 18.04 if 20.04 doesn't work.

Comment: @ubfan1, I've done that, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with 390.147 :( Thanks for you help!

Comment: You may answer your own question with some details of your solution, helping others and gaining some reputation points in the process.  If it gets an upvote, you may accept your own answer in a few days.

Comment: @ubfan1 I'll do that, just finishing some tests, Ubuntu 20.04.4 worked with nvidia on a fresh minimal install, but it freezes again when I made a system update. Kernel 5.13.0-30 (fresh install) and 5.13.0-40 (updated). Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've made this test, booted Ubuntu 22.04 LiveCD, switched to virtual terminal 3 (Ctrl+Alt+F3) and runned this commands: `sudo systemctl stop gdm3`, `sudo rmmod nouveau`. Installed nvidia drivers with `sudo apt install -y nvidia-driver-390`, loaded nvidia modules `sudo modprobe nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia`, started gdm `sudo systemctl start gdm3` and it works! I've made a test with glmark2 (got score 1653) and it showed GL_VERSION 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.147. I'll do more tests...

Answer (score 1):

To sum up, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel 5.13.0-30, with this Ubuntu/kernel version the nvidia-driver-390 works with my GeForce GT 630M.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with laptop MS Surface 2.
I sole this issue with my configuration :

1. `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-local.conf`

```
# This file lists those modules which we don't want to be loaded by
# alias expansion, usually so some other driver will be loaded for the
# device instead.

blacklist power_ctrl_logic
```

2. save this file
3. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
4. reboot